# Does inner join effect order by?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function a() which gives result in a specific order.

I want to do:

```
select final.*,tablex.name
from a() as final
inner join tablex on (a.key=tablex.key2)
```

My question is, can I guarantee that the join won't effect the order of rows as a() set it?

`a()` is:

```
select ....
from....
joins...
order by x,y,z
```

Comment: Without an `order by` there is no guarantee to _any_ order at all. The ***only*** (really: the _only_) way to get a guaranteed sort order is an `order by` - even without the join

Comment: The order by is implemented in a(), my question is if inner join that is done with a() results might cause diffrent order

Comment: `select * from a()` does not _guarantee_ any order (not even when you have an order by inside the function). You **have** to specify an `order by` in the final select.

Comment: Once more, there is no such thing as order(ordered table/subquery/etc) per se in SQL. **Without explicit `ORDER BY` in the most outer query the result order cannot be guaranteed**, Think about parallel execution when multiple threads process your data.

Comment: The simple answer is: No. But it also simply does not matter, because as  many here have already mentioned to get an ordered result you must apply the order by clause in the outermost select. You may even find that an order by within a subquery is disallowed (there are some exceptions but they are not relevant in this question).

Comment: So how did I always get the correct order so far? when I did Select * from a() .Did it retrived the data from cache or something like that?

Comment: The table must have been appropriately ordered and maybe you updated columns (this is only a guess) but if the data was modified the likelyhood is the ordering may have changed, hence why people are all saying use order by

Comment: @java Because you might have been lucky enough that the rows were inserted in the order you expected them to come out, and you use a particular database that happen to fetch the rows in that same order for your particular query. But all that might change if you delete some rows and insert new ones, or change your query a bit, or stuff more data in the table etc.

Comment: thx. I don't understan why I was downvoted. Maybe many people can say that the answer was no, but I doubt many poeple could actualy explain why. sometimes a simple question has deeper meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version:

The order of rows returned by a SQL query is not guaranteed in any way ***unless*** you use an `order by`

Any order you see without an `order by` is pure coincidence and can **not** be relied upon.

---

> *So how did I always get the correct order so far? when I did `Select * from a()`*

If your function is a **SQL** function, then the query inside the function is executed "as is" (it's essentially "inlined") so you only run a single query that *does* have an order by. If it's a PL/pgSQL function and the only thing it does is a `RETURN QUERY ...` then you again only have a *single* query that is executed which does have an `order by`.

Assuming you do use a SQL function, then running:

```
select final.*,tablex.name
from a() as final
   join tablex on a.key=tablex.key2
```

is equivalent to:

```
select final.*,tablex.name
from (
  -- this is your query inside the function
  select ...
  from ...
   join ...
  order by x,y,z
)  as final
   join tablex on a.key=tablex.key2;
```

In this case the `order by` inside the derived table doesn't make sense as it might be "overruled" by an overall `order by` statement. In fact some databases would outright reject this query (and I sometime wish Postgres would do as well).

Without an `order by` on the **overall* query, the database is free to choose any order of rows that it wants.

So to get back to the initial question:

> *can I guarantee that the join won't effect the order of rows as a() set it?*

The answer to that is a clear: NO - the order of the rows for that query is in no way guaranteed. If you *need* an order that you can rely on, you **have** to specify an `order by`.

I would even go so far to remove the `order by` from the function - what if someone runs: `select * from a() order by z,y,x` - I don't think Postgres will be smart enough to remove the `order by` *inside* the function.